# sum of a telescoping series

Tags: calculus

calculate the following $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \ln \left ( \frac{\left (\frac{n+3}{n+1}\right ) ^{n+1}}{\left (\frac{n+2}{n}\right )^n} \right )$$

I have manage to written it as $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \ln (1+\frac{2}{n+1} )^{n+1} - \ln (1+\frac{2}{n} )^n$$

Which is a telescoping series shouldn't the answer be $(a_n-L)$= $ln(2)^2-1$

Answer (score 2):

We have: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \ln \left(1+\frac{2}{n+1} \right)^{n+1} - \ln \left(1+\frac{2}{n} \right)^n = \lim_{n \to +\infty}  \ln \left(1+\frac{2}{n+1} \right)^{n+1} - \ln \left(3 \right),$$ which after applying the limit is: $$= \ln e^2 - \ln 3 = 2- \ln 3.$$

Comment: In general: $$\sum_{k=1}^n f(k+1)-f(k) = f(n+1)-f(1).$$

I plugged $n=1$ in $\ln (1+ 2/n)^n$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \log\left(1+\frac{2}{N+1}\right)^{N+1}=2$$

So, the series value is $2-\log(3)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Notice that $\ln(x^y)=y\ln(x)$. Put the power outside, you get the familiar telescoping series.

Answer (score 0):

If you set
$$
a_n=\left(\frac{n+2}{n}\right)^n, 
$$
then the given series can written as 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\ln\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right).
$$
Since
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\ln\left(\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left[\ln(a_{k+1})-\ln(a_k)\right]=\ln(a_n)-\ln(a_1)=\ln(a_n)-\ln3
$$
and
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)^n=e^2,
$$
we deduce that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\ln\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\ln(a_n)-\ln3\right]=\ln e^2-\ln3=2-\ln3.
$$